# Official iOS Keyboard Button Sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there any way I can get the official keyboard button sizes for iOS devices? I've obviously tried googling but have not found anything useful. I've gotten the keyboard size, but can't seem to find any information about the button sizes.